Performance loss with animation in Blender
when I play the same animation using Blender and C4D I get an absurd difference in performance in each software. In Blender it's running at 4~5 FPS with Simplify and Frame Dropping active, while in C4D everything is running well, at 30 FPS. Is this really a Blender problem or is there something I can do? I'm working with Blender at the moment and this is making it very difficult to make camera movements and so on.
Video showing the problem:
https://vimeo.com/933773993?share=copy
The mesh has 500.000 polygons, with no active subdivision modifiers.
